# Spring ReactiveCrudRepository @Query with PostgreSql throws PostgresqlBadGrammarException: [42P01]

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, project-reactor, r2dbc

Given a ReactiveCrudRepository with specified @Query which **passes unit test flawlessly using MariaDB** backend **but throws exception using PostgreSQL**.
Other Spring repository queries succeeds (findById, findByStockName). The structure is the same on both databases.
What can cause the error? Any ideas?
Any help is appreciated!

The entity (Stock.java):

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(schema = "experiment_schema", name = "stock_names")
public class Stock {

  public Stock(String stockName) {
    this.stockName = stockName;
  }

  @Id
  Integer id;

  @Length(min = 3, max = 3)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^([A-Z]){3}$")
  @Column(value = "stock_namee")
  String stockName;
}
```

The repository:

```
import net.sytes.csongi.springreactivetest.entities.Stock;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Repository
interface StockRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Stock,Integer> {

// this query fails using PostgreSQL.
// also tried @Query(value = "SELECT * from stock_names where stock_namee=:$1") with same result
  @Query(value = "SELECT * from stock_names  where stock_namee=:s")
  Flux<Stock> myCustomSearchFor(String s);
}
```

The service:

```
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import jakarta.validation.Validator;
import net.sytes.csongi.springreactivetest.entities.Stock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class StockService {

  @Autowired
  private StockRepository repository;
  @Autowired
  private Validator validator;

  public Mono<Stock> save(Stock stockToSave) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Stock>> constraintValidations = validator.validate(stockToSave);
    if (constraintValidations.isEmpty())
      return repository.save(stockToSave);
    throw new ConstraintViolationException("The following errors occured: ", constraintValidations);
  }

  public Mono<Void> deleteAll() {
    return repository.deleteAll();
  }

  public Flux<Stock> findStockByName(String stockName) {
    return repository.myCustomSearchFor(stockName);
  }
}
```

The test that succeeds/fails on MariaDB/PostgreSQL:

```
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import net.sytes.csongi.springreactivetest.entities.Stock;
import net.sytes.csongi.springreactivetest.repositories.StockService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringBootTest
public class StockServiceTest {

  private static final String VALID_STOCK_NAME = "EDE";

  @Autowired
  private StockService stockService;
  private Stock validStock;


  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    validStock = new Stock(VALID_STOCK_NAME);
    stockService.deleteAll().block();
  }
// ...
  @Test
  @DisplayName("Find by stock name should work")
  public void findByStockNameShouldWork() {
    stockService.save(validStock).block();
    List<Stock> loaded = stockService.findStockByName(VALID_STOCK_NAME).collectList().block();
    assertEquals(1,loaded.size());
  }
}
```

The application.yml:

```
spring:
 main:
  web-application-type: reactive
 r2dbc:
  url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:4444/product_db 
#  url: r2dbc:mariadb://localhost:7777/experiment_schema -> succeeds
  password: dev_xxx
  username: dev_xxx
 data:
  r2dbc:
   repositories:
    enabled: true
logging:
 level:
  root: info
```

The error message:

```
executeMany; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * from stock_names  where stock_namee=$1]
org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarException: executeMany; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * from stock_names  where stock_namee=$1]
    at app//org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.convertR2dbcException(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:243)
    at app//org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient.lambda$inConnectionMany$8(DefaultDatabaseClient.java:151)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Flux.java:7134)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorResume$29(Flux.java:7187)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.deferredError(FluxUsingWhen.java:398)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$RollbackInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:475)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
    at app//reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.maybeRecycleAndDrain(SimpleDequePool.java:531)
    at app//reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerInner.onComplete(SimpleDequePool.java:761)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
    at app//reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:873)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandleFuseable.java:238)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier$MonoSupplierSubscription.request(MonoSupplier.java:148)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxHandleFuseable.java:259)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreElements.java:72)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandleFuseable.java:163)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:48)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onError(MonoIgnoreElements.java:84)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:157)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:291)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:265)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onError(FluxUsingWhen.java:364)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:843)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerError(FluxFlatMap.java:864)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:991)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onError(FluxHandle.java:212)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:255)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:200)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.util.FluxDiscardOnCancel$FluxDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(FluxDiscardOnCancel.java:91)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:113)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:128)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:814)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:739)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.next(FluxCreate.java:161)
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$Conversation.emit(ReactorNettyClient.java:687)
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.emit(ReactorNettyClient.java:939)
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:813)
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:719)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:128)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:294)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:403)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800)
    at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499)
    at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397)
    at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base@18.0.2-ea/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710)
        at net.sytes.csongi.springreactivetest.StockServiceTest.findByStockNameShouldWork(StockServiceTest.java:74)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlBadGrammarException: [42P01] relation "stock_names" does not exist
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:96)
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:65)
    at app//io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.handleErrorResponse(ExceptionFactory.java:132)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:178)
    ... 43 more
```

Related gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.mariadb:r2dbc-mariadb:1.1.3'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the syntax of your SQL query
2. Use the correct parameter name: In your SQL query, you are using a placeholder $1, which suggests that you are using positional parameters. However, your method parameter name is `s`. You need to use the correct parameter name in your SQL query, either by changing the placeholder to `:s` or by using positional parameters and specifying the correct parameter index.

below is code snippet

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT * from stock_names  where stock_namee=:s")
  Flux<Stock> myCustomSearchFor(@Param("s")String s);
```